# try to get the type of a expression in template with declval and decltype

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I run into trouble by defining a data type as a result of an operation.
In the following example I have to Instances of a template class which have the 
template type "int".

I expect that the following expression results to int, but it did not!

```
typename A and B are both int
decltype( declval<A>+declval<B>)
```

Here is the full example:

```
#include <utility>
using namespace std;


template <typename T>  
class AV
{   
};  

template <typename T>
class Term
{   
};  

template <class A, class B>
auto operator +( AV<A>& a, AV<B>& b )->Term< int >
{ 
    Term< decltype(declval<A>+declval<B>) >t(&a,&b);
    //             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   invalid operands of types
    //                        '<unresolved overloaded function type>
    return t;
}


int main()
{   
    AV<int> a;
    AV<int> b;

    Term<int> x(a+b);
}
```

results in the following error ( gcc 4.8.2 )

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'Term<int> operator+(AV<A>&, AV<B>&) [with A = int; B = int]':
main.cpp:47:23:   required from here
main.cpp:39:111: error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator+'
     template <class A, class B> auto operator +( AV<A>& a, AV<B>& b )->Term< int > { Term< decltype(declval<A>+declval<B>) >t(&a,&b); return t; }
                                                                                                               ^
main.cpp:39:111: error: invalid operands of types '<unresolved overloaded function type>' and '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to binary 'operator+'
make: *** [go] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`declval<T>` is a function. you have to call it, to form value expressions to give to `decltype`

try

```
Term< decltype(declval<A>()+declval<B>()) >t(&a,&b);
```

Comment: Yeah, I had the same answer but I was busy writing the missing constructors. Considering OP probably made a SSCCE, I suppose it's pointless.

Comment: `declval<T>` is NOT a class. It is a function template, which exists in the library as *declaration* without any definition!

Comment: @Nawaz Whether a definition exists is unspecified. In libstdc++, a definition does exist, and it is a definition that uses a static assertion to force a meaningful compile-time error. That's perfectly valid.

Comment: what t(&a, &b); is supposed to do? Just curious as it does not compile on Visual Studio 2013, unless I modify x to Term<decltype(a+b)> x; or Term<int> y(decltype(a + b)());

Comment: @nmenezes It is a local variable declaration of `t`, where `&a` and `&b` are arguments for the constructor of `Term`. It doesn't compile because the code in the question omits the constructor declaration, but presumably the real code does have it.